# SQL Data Reader - handling Null column values

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I'm using a SQLdatareader to build POCOs from a database. The code works except when it encounters a null value in the database. For example, if the FirstName column in the database contains a null value, an exception is thrown.

```
employee.FirstName = sqlreader.GetString(indexFirstName);
```

How can I handle null values in this situation?

Comment: I think the  Generic function created by @Vijai should get more recognition in this thread. It worked really well for me and I don't need to pass the data reader object each time. many popular answers passing data reader object which is unnecessary and heavy.

Answer (score 592, accepted):

You need to check for `IsDBNull`:

```
if(!SqlReader.IsDBNull(indexFirstName))
{
  employee.FirstName = sqlreader.GetString(indexFirstName);
}
```

That's your only reliable way to detect and handle this situation.

I wrapped those things into extension methods and tend to return a default value if the column is indeed `null`:

```
public static string SafeGetString(this SqlDataReader reader, int colIndex)
{
   if(!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
       return reader.GetString(colIndex);
   return string.Empty;
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
employee.FirstName = SqlReader.SafeGetString(indexFirstName);
```

and you'll never have to worry about an exception or a `null` value again.

Comment: If someone needs the **column name** rather than the index, you can do: `int colIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(fieldname);` and easily overload @marc_s's `SafeGetString` function.

Comment: Also can be done like this: int ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal("col_name");
uint? val = reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? (uint?)null : reader.GetUInt32(ordinal);

Answer (score 246):

You should use the `as` operator combined with the `??` operator for default values. Value types will need to be read as nullable and given a default.

```
employee.FirstName = sqlreader[indexFirstName] as string;
employee.Age = sqlreader[indexAge] as int? ?? default(int);
```

The `as` operator handles the casting including the check for DBNull.

Comment: If someone changes the Age column from being an int to an SQL bigint (c# long), your code will fail silently by returning 0. The answer from ZXX is more reliable IMO.

Comment: I wonder if you can override the default(int) to be -1 instead of 0

Comment: @Chris - You should be able to just replace default(int) with -1.

Comment: @Stevo3000 You are correct! I tried that and it worked as you said right after I posted, but I forgot to come back to this page :)

Comment: Be aware that using "as" here can hide index errors.  If you accidentally use `sqlreader[indexAge] as string ?? ""`, you'll always get `""`.  Consider whether you really want `(int?)sqlreader[indexAge] ?? defaultValue` instead, so if your SQL changes you get exceptions instead of bad values.

@Stevo3000: default(int) is 0, not -1.
@Chris: Make sure you're using the one you really want.

Comment: @me22 - Please read the earlier comments in regards to `default(int)`, nobody on here has suggested `default(int)` is -1. Secondly your example of why not to use `as` is naive at best, of course you could write the wrong thing thats one of the dangers with any line of code. The case for using `as` is that it allows the programmer to code against data that may contain DBNull (either from tables that allow it or more usefully from joins).

Answer (score 37):

```
employee.FirstName = sqlreader[indexFirstName] as string;
```

For integers, if you cast to a nullable int, you can use GetValueOrDefault()

```
employee.Age = (sqlreader[indexAge] as int?).GetValueOrDefault();
```

or the  null-coalescing operator (`??`).

```
employee.Age = (sqlreader[indexAge] as int?) ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 28):

`IsDbNull(int)` is usually much slower than using methods like `GetSqlDateTime` and then comparing to `DBNull.Value`. Try these extension methods for `SqlDataReader`.

```
public static T Def<T>(this SqlDataReader r, int ord)
{
    var t = r.GetSqlValue(ord);
    if (t == DBNull.Value) return default(T);
    return ((INullable)t).IsNull ? default(T) : (T)t;
}

public static T? Val<T>(this SqlDataReader r, int ord) where T:struct
{
    var t = r.GetSqlValue(ord);
    if (t == DBNull.Value) return null;
    return ((INullable)t).IsNull ? (T?)null : (T)t;
}

public static T Ref<T>(this SqlDataReader r, int ord) where T : class
{
    var t = r.GetSqlValue(ord);
    if (t == DBNull.Value) return null;
    return ((INullable)t).IsNull ? null : (T)t;
}
```

Use them like this:

```
var dd = r.Val<DateTime>(ords[4]);
var ii = r.Def<int>(ords[0]);
int nn = r.Def<int>(ords[0]);
```

Comment: I'm finding that the explicit operators on the System.Data.SqlTypes types are throwing errors everywhere trying to use this code...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21024873/1508467 for an explanation of why this sometimes fails (try using Val<int> to read a SQL int column).

Answer (score 24):

`if(reader.IsDBNull(ColumnIndex)) {// logic}` works as many answers says.

And I want to mention if you working with column names, just comparing types may be more comfortable.

```
if(reader["TeacherImage"].GetType() == typeof(DBNull)) { //logic }
```

Comment: This also works on old versions of System.Data and .NET FW

Comment: Only this worked for me may be due to old .NET FW

Answer (score 16):

I don't think there's a **NULL** column value, when rows are returned within a datareader using the column name.

If you do `datareader["columnName"].ToString();` it will always give you a value that can be a empty string (`String.Empty` if you need to compare).

I would use the following and wouldn't worry too much:

```
employee.FirstName = sqlreader["columnNameForFirstName"].ToString();
```

Comment: You can do a reader[FieldName] == DBNull.Value, to check for NULL's

Answer (score 15):

You can write a Generic function to check Null and include default value when it is NULL. Call this when reading Datareader

```
public T CheckNull<T>(object obj)
        {
            return (obj == DBNull.Value ? default(T) : (T)obj);
        }
```

When reading the Datareader use

```
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            tblBPN_InTrRecon Bpn = new tblBPN_InTrRecon();
                            Bpn.BPN_Date = CheckNull<DateTime?>(dr["BPN_Date"]);
                            Bpn.Cust_Backorder_Qty = CheckNull<int?>(dr["Cust_Backorder_Qty"]);
                            Bpn.Cust_Min = CheckNull<int?>(dr["Cust_Min"]);
                         }
```

Comment: I think this is the best common method to handle any kind of null. I don't know why this answer is not popular.

Answer (score 13):

One way to do it is to check for db nulls:

```
employee.FirstName = (sqlreader.IsDBNull(indexFirstName) 
    ? ""
    : sqlreader.GetString(indexFirstName));
```

Answer (score 12):

This Solution is less vendor-dependent and works with an SQL, OleDB, and MySQL Reader:

```
public static string GetStringSafe(this IDataReader reader, int colIndex)
{
    return GetStringSafe(reader, colIndex, string.Empty);
}

public static string GetStringSafe(this IDataReader reader, int colIndex, string defaultValue)
{
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
        return reader.GetString(colIndex);
    else
        return defaultValue;
}

public static string GetStringSafe(this IDataReader reader, string indexName)
{
    return GetStringSafe(reader, reader.GetOrdinal(indexName));
}

public static string GetStringSafe(this IDataReader reader, string indexName, string defaultValue)
{
    return GetStringSafe(reader, reader.GetOrdinal(indexName), defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: Copying and customizing this code directly into an extensions class right now.

Answer (score 11):

By influencing from [getpsyched's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52204396/1262673), I created a generic method which checks column value by its name

```
public static T SafeGet<T>(this System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader, string nameOfColumn)
{
  var indexOfColumn = reader.GetOrdinal(nameOfColumn);
  return reader.IsDBNull(indexOfColumn) ? default(T) : reader.GetFieldValue<T>(indexOfColumn);
}
```

Usage:

```
var myVariable = SafeGet<string>(reader, "NameOfColumn")
```

Comment: I don't know who you are, but bless you. This function saved over three hours of work.

Answer (score 8):

What I tend to do is replace the null values in the SELECT statement with something appropriate.

```
SELECT ISNULL(firstname, '') FROM people
```

Here I replace every null with a blank string. Your code won't throw in error in that case.

Comment: If possible, use this avoid nulls.  Otherwise, I like Sonny Boy's answer of helper methods.

Comment: Why a static, separate helper method? Doesn't an extension method on the SqlDataReader seem more compelling and more intuitive??

Comment: The answer should tell about the C# way of handling it , not using SQL. In my case, I don't have control over SQL query.

Answer (score 6):

Check `sqlreader.IsDBNull(indexFirstName)` before you try to read it.

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to the answer by marc_s, you can use a more generic extension method to get values from the SqlDataReader:

```
public static T SafeGet<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, int col)
    {
        return reader.IsDBNull(col) ? default(T) : reader.GetFieldValue<T>(col);
    }
```

Comment: I would not call this method "SafeGet" because if T is a struct it will convert nulls to the non-null default for T - not really safe. Perhaps "GetValueOrDefault".

Comment: @RhysJones Why would you have T as a struct in this case? Even if you do I would argue that the non-null default in the struct is the expected behavior.

Comment: @RhysJones But I agree that this method might not be safe, it would need to handle exceptions like InvalidCastException from the SqlDataReader.

Answer (score 4):

how to about creating helper methods

For String

```
private static string MyStringConverter(object o)
    {
        if (o == DBNull.Value || o == null)
            return "";

        return o.ToString();
    }
```

Usage

```
MyStringConverter(read["indexStringValue"])
```

For Int

```
 private static int MyIntonverter(object o)
    {
        if (o == DBNull.Value || o == null)
            return 0;

        return Convert.ToInt32(o);
    }
```

Usage

```
MyIntonverter(read["indexIntValue"])
```

For Date

```
private static DateTime? MyDateConverter(object o)
    {
        return (o == DBNull.Value || o == null) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(o);
    }
```

Usage

```
MyDateConverter(read["indexDateValue"])
```

Note: for DateTime declare varialbe as

```
DateTime? variable;
```

Answer (score 4):

None of these was quite what i wanted:

```
 public static T GetFieldValueOrDefault<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string name)
 {
     int index = reader.GetOrdinal(name);
     T value = reader.IsDBNull(index) ? default(T) : reader.GetFieldValue<T>(index);
     return value;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you would want to use:

```
SqlReader.IsDBNull(indexFirstName)
```

Answer (score 2):

We use a series of static methods to pull all of the values out of our data readers.  So in this case we'd be calling `DBUtils.GetString(sqlreader(indexFirstName))`  The benefit of creating static/shared methods is that you don't have to do the same checks over and over and over...

The static method(s) would contain code to check for nulls (see other answers on this page).

Answer (score 2):

You may use the conditional operator:

```
employee.FirstName = sqlreader["indexFirstName"] != DBNull.Value ? sqlreader[indexFirstName].ToString() : "";
```

Comment: Same as one of the answers below, but 8 years behind!

Answer (score 2):

Here is helper class which others can use if they need based on @marc_s answer:

```
public static class SQLDataReaderExtensions
    {
        public static int SafeGetInt(this SqlDataReader dataReader, string fieldName)
        {
            int fieldIndex = dataReader.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
            return dataReader.IsDBNull(fieldIndex) ? 0 : dataReader.GetInt32(fieldIndex);
        }

        public static int? SafeGetNullableInt(this SqlDataReader dataReader, string fieldName)
        {
            int fieldIndex = dataReader.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
            return dataReader.GetValue(fieldIndex) as int?;
        }

        public static string SafeGetString(this SqlDataReader dataReader, string fieldName)
        {
            int fieldIndex = dataReader.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
            return dataReader.IsDBNull(fieldIndex) ? string.Empty : dataReader.GetString(fieldIndex);
        }

        public static DateTime? SafeGetNullableDateTime(this SqlDataReader dataReader, string fieldName)
        {
            int fieldIndex = dataReader.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
            return dataReader.GetValue(fieldIndex) as DateTime?;
        }

        public static bool SafeGetBoolean(this SqlDataReader dataReader, string fieldName)
        {
            return SafeGetBoolean(dataReader, fieldName, false);
        }

        public static bool SafeGetBoolean(this SqlDataReader dataReader, string fieldName, bool defaultValue)
        {
            int fieldIndex = dataReader.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
            return dataReader.IsDBNull(fieldIndex) ? defaultValue : dataReader.GetBoolean(fieldIndex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of answers here with useful info (and some wrong info) spread about, I'd like to bring it all together.

The short answer to the question is to check for DBNull - almost everyone agrees on this bit :)

Rather than using a helper method to read nullable values per SQL data type a generic method allows us to address this with a lot less code. However, you can't have a single generic method for both nullable value types and reference types, this is discussed at length in 
[Nullable type as a generic parameter possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209160/nullable-type-as-a-generic-parameter-possible?rq=1) and [C# generic type constraint for everything nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831157/c-sharp-generic-type-constraint-for-everything-nullable).

So, following on from the answers from @ZXX and @getpsyched we end up with this, 2 methods for getting nullable values and I've added a 3rd for non-null values (it completes the set based on method naming).

```
public static T? GetNullableValueType<T>(this SqlDataReader sqlDataReader, string columnName) where T : struct
{
    int columnOrdinal = sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(columnName);
    return sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(columnOrdinal) ? (T?)null : sqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<T>(columnOrdinal);
}

public static T GetNullableReferenceType<T>(this SqlDataReader sqlDataReader, string columnName) where T : class
{
    int columnOrdinal = sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(columnName);
    return sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(columnOrdinal) ? null : sqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<T>(columnOrdinal);
}

public static T GetNonNullValue<T>(this SqlDataReader sqlDataReader, string columnName)
{
    int columnOrdinal = sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(columnName);
    return sqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<T>(columnOrdinal);
}
```

I usually use column names, alter these if you use column indexes. Based on these method names I can tell whether I'm expecting the data to be nullable or not, quite useful when looking at code written a long time ago.

Tips;

- Not having nullable columns in the database avoids this issue. If you
  have control over the database then columns should be non-null by
  default and only nullable where necessary.
- Don't cast database values
  with the C# 'as' operator because if the cast is wrong it will
  silently return null.
- Using a [default value expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions) will change
  database nulls to non-null values for value types like int, datetime,
  bit etc.

Lastly, whilst testing the above methods across all SQL Server data types I discovered you can't directly get a char[] from a SqlDataReader, if you want a char[] you will have to get a string and use ToCharArray().

Answer (score 2):

in c# 7.0 we can do :

```
var a = reader["ERateCode"] as string;
var b = reader["ERateLift"] as int?;
var c = reader["Id"] as int?;
```

so it will keep null value if it is.

Answer (score 2):

I did my best to reimplement the `Field` method from `DataTable`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field

It will throw if you try to convert a `DBNull.Value` to a non-nullable type. Otherwise it will convert `DBNull.Value` to `null`.

I haven't fully tested it.

```
public static T Field<T>(this SqlDataReader sqlDataReader, string columnName)
{
    int columnIndex = sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(columnName);
    if (sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(columnIndex))
    {
        if (default(T) != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("Cannot convert DBNULL value to type " + typeof(T).Name);
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return sqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<T>(columnIndex);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string fname = sqlDataReader.Field<string>("FirstName");
int? age = sqlDataReader.Field<int?>("Age");
int yearsOfExperience = sqlDataReader.Field<int?>("YearsEx") ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

and / or use ternary operator with assignment:

```
employee.FirstName = rdr.IsDBNull(indexFirstName))? 
                     String.Empty: rdr.GetString(indexFirstName);
```

replace the default (when null) value as appropriate for each property type...

Answer (score 1):

I am using the code listed below to handle null cells in an Excel sheet that is read in to a datatable.

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(2))
{
   row["Oracle"] = (string)reader[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void Render(IList<ListData> list, IDataReader reader)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                listData.DownUrl = (reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns["DownUrl"] != null) ? Convert.ToString(reader["DownUrl"]) : null;
                //没有这一列时，让其等于null
                list.Add(listData);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is dependent on indexFirstName which should be the zero-based column ordinal.

```
if(!sqlReader.IsDBNull(indexFirstName))
{
  employee.FirstName = sqlreader.GetString(indexFirstName);
}
```

If you don't know the column index but wan't to check a name you can use this extension method instead:

```
public static class DataRecordExtensions
{
    public static bool HasColumn(this IDataRecord dr, string columnName)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (dr.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use the method like this:

```
if(sqlReader.HasColumn("FirstName"))
{
  employee.FirstName = sqlreader["FirstName"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but maybe someone still need an answer

in real i worked around this issue like that

For int :

```
public static object GatDataInt(string Query, string Column)
    {
        SqlConnection DBConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        if (DBConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            DBConn.Open();
        SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(Query, DBConn);
        SqlDataReader RDR = CMD.ExecuteReader();
        if (RDR.Read())
        {
            var Result = RDR[Column];
            RDR.Close();
            DBConn.Close();
            return Result;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

the same for string just return "" instead of 0 as "" is empty string

so you can use it like

```
int TotalPoints = GatDataInt(QueryToGetTotalPoints, TotalPointColumn) as int?;
```

and

```
string Email = GatDatastring(QueryToGetEmail, EmailColumn) as string;
```

very flexible so you can insert any query to read any column and it'll never return with error

Answer (score 1):

neat one-liner:

```
    while (dataReader.Read())
{
    employee.FirstName = (!dataReader.IsDBNull(dataReader.GetOrdinal("FirstName"))) ? dataReader["FirstName"].ToString() : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert handles DbNull sensibly.

```
employee.FirstName = Convert.ToString(sqlreader.GetValue(indexFirstName));
```

Comment: Note that DBNull is converted to an empty string, not a null value.

Answer (score -3):

you can ever check for this as well

```
if(null !=x && x.HasRows)
{ ....}
```

Comment: -1 This is not the point: we are handling the case of a null column value, not that of a null or empty `SqlDataReader`