# casting datareader value to a to a Nullable variable

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to run the following code but get a casting error.
How can I rewrite my code to achive the same ?

```
boolResult= (bool?)dataReader["BOOL_FLAG"] ?? true;
intResult= (int?)dataReader["INT_VALUE"] ?? 0;
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what the actual value contained in dataReader["BOOL_FLAG"] and dataReader["INT_VALUE"] are?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the "IsDbNull" method on the data reader... for example:

```
bool? result = dataReader.IsDbNull(dataReader["Bool_Flag"]) ? null : (bool)dataReader["Bool_Flag"]
```

**Edit**

You'd need to do something akin to:
bool? nullBoolean = null;

you'd have

```
bool? result = dataReader.IsDbNull(dataReader["Bool_Flag"]) ? nullBoolean : (bool)dataReader["Bool_Flag"]
```

Comment: You're right, I updated my answer... I forgot that it can't tell if null is a string, bool?, MyCustomObject or what

Comment: you can simply do `? (bool?)null : (bool)dataReader["Bool_Flag"]`

Comment: What if the tested column is a Datetime field?  The IsDbNull method expects an integer.  Nevermind I suppose I can do the ordinal lookup in the method call as an argument.

Answer (score 12):

Consider doing it in a function.

Here's something I used in the past (you can make this an extension method in .net 4):

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(SqlDataReader dataReader, System.Enum columnIndex)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(columnIndex);

    return !dataReader.IsDBNull(index) ? (T)dataReader.GetValue(index) : default(T);
}
```

**Edit**

As an extension (not tested, but you get the idea), and using column names instead of index:

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this SqlDataReader dataReader, string columnName)
{

    return !dataReader.IsDBNull(dataReader[columnName]) ? (T)dataReader.GetValue(dataReader[columnName]) : default(T);
}
```

usage:

```
bool? flag = dataReader.GetValueOrDefault("BOOL_COLUMN");
```

Comment: I like the second extension method. However, since `IsDBNull()` only takes an `int`, you'll have to call something like: `dataReader.IsDBNull(dataReader.GetOrdinal(columnName))`

Comment: Usage has to be: bool? flag = dataReader.GetValueOrDefault<bool?>("BOOL_COLUMN");

Answer (score 6):

There's an answer here that might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3308515/1255900

You can use the "as" keyword. Note the caution mentioned in the comments.

```
nullableBoolResult = dataReader["BOOL_FLAG"] as bool?;
```

Or, if you are not using nullables, as in your original post:

```
boolResult = (dataReader["BOOL_FLAG"] as bool?) ?? 0;
```

Comment: I tried the dataReader["long_col"] as long? for a nullable long, but it set the value to null in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool? boolResult = null;
int? intResult = null;

if (dataReader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("BOOL_FLAG")) == false)
{
  boolResult  = dataReader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("BOOL_FLAG"));
}
else
{
  boolResult = true;
}

if (dataReader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("INT_VALUE")) == false)
{
   intResult= dataReader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("INT_VALUE"));
}
else
{
   intResult = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my shot at an extension method. Column name semantics and falls back to `default(T)` when a null is encountered.

```
public static class DbExtensions
{
    public static T ReadAs<T>(this IDataReader reader, string col)
    {
        object val = reader[col];
        if (val is DBNull)
        {
            // Use the default if the column is null
            return default(T);
        }
        return (T)val;
    }
}
```

Here is the sample usage. Remember that despite `string` being a reference type, it will still fail to cast to `null` from a `DBNull`. The same is true with `int?`.

```
public Facility Bind(IDataReader reader)
{
    var x = new Facility();
    x.ID = reader.ReadAs<Guid>("ID");
    x.Name = reader.ReadAs<string>("Name");
    x.Capacity = reader.ReadAs<int?>("Capacity");
    x.Description = reader.ReadAs<string>("Description");
    x.Address = reader.ReadAs<string>("Address");
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using extension method:

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault <T> (this SqlDataReader reader, string column) {
    var isDbNull = reader[column] == DBNull.Value;
    return !isDbNull ? (T) reader[column] : default (T);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I found the inspiration for this somewhere around the interweb but I can't seem to find the original source anymore. Anyway, below you find a utility class which allows to define an extension method on DataReader, like this:

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    public static TResult Get<TResult>(this IDataReader reader, string name)
    {
        return reader.Get<TResult>(reader.GetOrdinal(name));
    }

    public static TResult Get<TResult>(this IDataReader reader, int c)
    {
        return ConvertTo<TResult>.From(reader[c]);
    }
 }
```

Usage:

```
  reader.Get<bool?>("columnname")
```

or

```
 reader.Get<int?>(5)
```

Here's the enabling utility class:

```
public static class ConvertTo<T>
{
    // 'Factory method delegate', set in the static constructor
    public static readonly Func<object, T> From;

    static ConvertTo()
    {
        From = Create(typeof(T));
    }

    private static Func<object, T> Create(Type type)
    {
        if (!type.IsValueType) { return ConvertRefType; }
        if (type.IsNullableType())
        {
            return (Func<object, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, T>), typeof(ConvertTo<T>).GetMethod("ConvertNullableValueType", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(new[] { type.GetGenericArguments()[0] }));
        }
        return ConvertValueType;
    }

    // ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Local
    // (used via reflection!)
    private static TElem? ConvertNullableValueType<TElem>(object value) where TElem : struct
    {
        if (DBNull.Value == value) { return null; }
        return (TElem)value;
    }
    // ReSharper restore UnusedMember.Local


    private static T ConvertRefType(object value)
    {
        if (DBNull.Value != value) { return (T)value; }
        return default(T);
    }

    private static T ConvertValueType(object value)
    {
        if (DBNull.Value == value)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Value is DbNull");
        }
        return (T)value;
    }
}
```

EDIT: makes use of the IsNullableType() extension method defined like so:

```
    public static bool IsNullableType(this Type type)
    {
        return 
            (type.IsGenericType && !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition) && 
            (typeof (Nullable<>) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a DBNull is not the same thing as null, so you cannot cast from one to the other.  As the other poster said, you can check for DBNull using the IsDBNull() method.

Answer (score -2):

Try [this](http://vecklare.blogspot.se/2012/08/a-generic-way-to-read-data-from.html) version. It performs some basic conversion and manages default values as well.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.