# The problem when I try to read nullable value in c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, nullable

I am trying to read my database. I have an column stores int values or null values. When I try to read this column i normally use this line of code;

```
int Score = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Score"]);
```

but it can be null. So i cant convert it to int. Then I tried ;

```
bool tryGetScore = int.TryParse(reader["Score"], out player1Score);
```

but i cant parse this value neither. It says "Cannot convert from 'Object' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan'"

How can i read this value. Whenever i face a null, my program crashes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [casting datareader value to a to a Nullable variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409936/casting-datareader-value-to-a-to-a-nullable-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `isDbNull` for example

```cs
int scoreIdx = reader.GetOrdinal("Score");
int score = reader.IsDbNull(scoreIdx) ? 
  0 : reader.GetInt32(scoreIdx);
```

Comment: its not working. it says cannot convert from object to int

Comment: So the problem is not related to the `NULL` value. I undated the answer