# Using mySQL query results as variables in VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am very new to VB.net and I am finding it exceptionally difficult to pass an sql query result (string) into a variable.

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get anything but boolean output from my reader function.

I need to obtain staff "account type" from my staff table and then define that account type in a variable.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial about using MySQL and VB together:

- http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqlvisualbasictutorial/

The piece from this that may be of interest to you:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim cs As String = "Database=testdb;Data Source=localhost;" _
        & "User Id=testuser;Password=test623"

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(cs)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim stm As String = "SELECT * FROM Authors"
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(stm, conn)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0) & ": " _ 
                & reader.GetString(1))
        End While

        reader.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
      Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    Finally
      conn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Note the `MySqlDataReader` (`reader`) object. This lets you get various types of data back. You need to know the column type you are reading, and use the appropriate method.

For example if you're reading a boolean, you would write:

```
reader.GetBoolean(0)
```

Or a DateTime:

```
reader.GetDateTime(0)
```

This example uses int arguments to represent the column number, but I find this less intuitive than using the column name. Fortunately `MySqlDataReader` supports column names as well:

```
reader.GetString("account_type")
```

The example doesn't show reading these values into variables, but it's fairly trivial:

```
Dim accountType As String
...
accountType = reader.GetString("account_type")
```

(This assumes that your account type column is a string.)

Hopefully this helps get you on the right track.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998919/mysqldatareader-retrieving-null-value-problem-in-c-sharp for dealing with DBNULL values, it's for C# but applies just the same to VB.

Comment: Thanks so much. reader.getstring("account_type") worked like a charm.  I really appreciate your help.