# vb.net DBNull to string error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a sub which just adds the values from a access db to textboxes. However, some of the fields in the db contain null values or are empty and this is causing vb to throw an error, 'Cannot convert from DBNull to string'.

How can I fix this based on my posted code or if someone could  post a tutorial for this type of event, as I am a new user struggling to make sense of this. Many thanks

```
Sub add()
        While dr.Read()
            txtname.Text = dr(0).ToString()
            txtfathername.Text = dr(1).ToString()
            txtaddress.Text = dr(2).ToString()
            txtemail.Text = dr(3).ToString()
        End While

    End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Sub filllistview()
        Try
            'creatconn()
            cn.Open()
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * from Postings", cn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While dr.Read()
                ListView1.Items.Add(dr(0).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(1))
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(2))
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(3))

            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            dr.Close()
            cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

Sub showcontectsinlistview()
        Try
            'creatconn()
            cn.Open()
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from Postings where [Code]='" & ListView1.Text & "'", cn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            add()

        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            dr.Close()
            cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect if the data coming from the row is empty first, then replace it with other values with will make it into a string, then you can pass it onto your textbox

Use the nothing function:

```
dim x as string
if dr(0).value = nothing then
    x = "Null data"
else
    x = dr(0).value
end if
```

It seems the problems stems on the part when you read the data from the database. can you try changing your query to not output null values?

something like

```
   SELECT Field
   FROM Table
   WHERE Not(Field) is null;
```

Comment: Does x cover dr(0) to dr(4)? or do I need to declare var for each line. Thanks

Comment: Would x handle dr(0),dr(1) etc. Please see my earlier comment. Thanks

Comment: you can use x for each instance of dr, friend

Comment: Malky I have tried after setting your code and replacing mine with what I thought was correct but causes error. ListView1.Items.Add(dr(0).x)

Comment: Please see my comment, friend.

Comment: That means I have to check all fields for null or empty value. In there no way to check in the loop? Thanks

Comment: I shall start a new post because I think we have moved from original question as I am 50% there. Thanks and please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just check if the values are not NULL

```
Sub add()
    While dr.Read()
        If dr(0) Then txtname.Text = dr(0).ToString()
        If dr(1) Then txtfathername.Text = dr(1).ToString()
        If dr(2) Then txtaddress.Text = dr(2).ToString()
        If dr(3) Then txtemail.Text = dr(3).ToString()
    End While
End Sub
```

There probably is a better way though...

Comment: You could maybe add a function to check if the value is NULL

Comment: Or you could check if the length is higher as 0 `If dr(0).length > 0 Then txtname.Text = dr(0).ToString`.

Comment: I thought something like this would do it: If(IsDBNull(Dr(2), string.Empty, Dr(2)) but not sure how to include in my Sub filllistview() example above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check if the value `IsDBNull` first like so

```
Dim value As String = If(dr.IsDBNull(dr(0)), "", dr(0).ToString())
```

then use the `value`

you can put this logic into a method and do the return from there.

or in your method:

```
Sub add()
    While dr.Read()
        If dr(0) Then txtname.Text = If(dr.IsDBNull(dr(0)), "", dr(0).ToString())
        If dr(1) Then txtfathername.Text = If(dr.IsDBNull(dr(1)), "", dr(1).ToString())
        If dr(2) Then txtaddress.Text = If(dr.IsDBNull(dr(2)), "", dr(2).ToString())
        If dr(3) Then txtemail.Text = If(dr.IsDBNull(dr(3)), "", dr(3).ToString())
    End While
End Sub
```

[SqlDataReader.IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

also check other SO answers: [SQL Data Reader - handling Null column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772025/sql-data-reader-handling-null-column-values)

```
.Add(dr(0).ToString())
```

becomes:

```
.Add(If(dr.IsDBNull(dr(0)), "", dr(0).ToString()))
```

Comment: Ric This now causes an error in my listview, code I have placed in original question. I have posted screenshot of error. Thanks

Comment: Are you doing the IsDBNull check and returning an empty string instead of the null?

Comment: Ric I am using the code you posted. However, I am posting another piece of code that calls the add(). How do I know what I am returning? Thanks

Comment: Whenever you try to access a column value of the reader for instance dr(0) you should be doing dr.IsDBNull(dr(0)) first to check for the null

Comment: Ric How would that code in Sub filllistview() example above. Thanks

Comment: Ric errors with: 'index out of bounds of the array' whatever that means.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution is following ...

```
Sub Add()
    While dr.Read()
        txtname.Text = dr(0) & ""
        txtfathername.Text = dr(1) & ""
        txtaddress.Text = dr(2) & ""
        txtemail.Text = dr(3) & ""
    End While
End Sub
```

This solution works also with column name !

```
Sub Add()
    While dr.Read()
        txtname.Text = dr("name") & ""
        txtfathername.Text = dr("father_name") & ""
        txtaddress.Text = dr("address") & ""
        txtemail.Text = dr("email") & ""
    End While
End Sub
```

When `dr("colum_name")` is DBNULL, `.Text` value is an empty string.

When column type is an integer, you can also initialize `.Text` property with "0" String.

```
txtNrChildren.Text = CStr(dr("nr_children") + "0")
```