# How to work with null incoming from database

Tags: c#, database

I'm getting this error

> This method or property cannot be called on Null values

on this line `id = rd.GetString(0);`. How to solve it?

```
public string MaxId()
{
    string id = "";

    con.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM Customer";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rd.Read()){
        id = rd.GetString(0);
    }
    con.Close();
    return id;
}
```

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772025/sql-data-reader-handling-null-column-values

Comment: Give your question a **meaningful** title, please.

Answer (score 2):

add this

```
!rd.IsDBNull(0)
```

before

```
id = rd.GetString(0);
```

So, your code would look like

```
public string MaxId()

    {
    string id = "";

    con.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM Customer";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rd.Read())

    {
        if(!rd.IsDBNull(0))
            id = rd.GetString(0);
    }
    con.Close();
    return id;
```