# Why can I not cast a smallint from MSSQL to int like this: int x = (int)dt.Rows[x]["smallIntColumn"]

Tags: c#, casting

Just looking for an explanation on this - the question pretty much explains it all but here's an bit extra:

```
//this line works OK
int i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[x]["SmallintColumnName"]);

//this line errors out
int j = (int)dt.Rows[x]["SmallintColumnName"];
```

I find this strange but I guess there's a valid argument on why this is like it is.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever - it is an InvalidCastException - Specified cast is not valid.
I guess I need to read up on boxing and unboxing. I assumed that both would work. 
Now I have just tried:

```
int k = (Int32)r_dtAttribute.Rows[x]["CultureId"];
```

this also fails with the same InvalidCastException - so can anyone tell me what the actual difference is between

```
//fails
int k = (Int32)r_dtAttribute.Rows[x]["CultureId"];
```

and

```
//works
int i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[x]["SmallintColumnName"]);
```

What does the Convert.ToInt32 function do that just casting with (Int32) doesn't do?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error? Usually they are pretty good at telling you why they can't do it.

Comment: possibly for `null`, `Convert.ToInt32` return `0`, but `(int)` raise exception

Comment: [Boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx): "Unboxing is an explicit conversion from the type **object** to a value type ..." and "Attempting to unbox a reference to an incompatible value type causes an `InvalidCastException`."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever why you think that OP have `InvalidCastException` ? :-)

Comment: @Grundy - experience. The database type is `smallint` which ADO will *never* return as a boxed `int32`. As such, `(int)` can *never* work, whether the particular row is returning `null` or an actual value.

Comment: Hi guys - thanks for your help - @Damien_The_Unbeliever it is an InvalidCastException  - I just added another test to the question regarding (Int32) - can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dt.Rows[x]["SmallintColumnName"]` is going to return an `object`. What the database returned has actually been translated (by ADO.Net) into an `Int16`<sup>1</sup>, but since the return value of the expression is `object`, the value has been *boxed*.

I linked in a comment to the article on [Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx). Your expression:

```
int j = (int)dt.Rows[x]["SmallintColumnName"];
```

Is an attempt to *unbox* a value from an `object`. But the rules of boxing and unboxing say that you can only unbox exactly the same type that was boxed (except some weird rules to do with enums and their underlying types, IIRC). But since we know that what we have is a boxed `Int16`, you're going to get an `InvalidCastException`.

What you could do is:

```
int j = (int)(Int16)dt.Rows[x]["SmallintColumnName"];
```

or even just:

```
int j = (Int16)dt.Rows[x]["SmallintColumnName"];
```

Where we *first* unbox the `Int16` value and then explicitly (first example) or implicitly (second) *cast* the `Int16` to an `Int32`. It's slightly unfortunate that casting and unboxing look exactly the same.

`Convert.ToInt32(object)` is a whole different beast and supports all kinds of conversions. What it actually does is to cast the argument to the `IConvertible` interface (which `Int16` supports) and then calls the `ToInt32` method on the `Int16`. That, in turn, turns around and calls `Convert.ToInt32(Int16)`, having switched back from being a boxed `Int16` to just being a plain `Int16`, which finally gets implicitly converted into an `Int32`. Magic.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've tried, but I think failed, to be consistent throughout the answer in the type names I use. But be aware that `short` and `Int16` are exactly the same type. `int` and `Int32` are also the same types. So switching your attempt from `(int)` to `(Int32)` didn't actually cause any change in the compiled code.

Comment: Awesome answer - thanks a lot!!!! - one more question - I suppose I could test this using a loop of 100,000s of "unboxes" and the same number of calls to Convert.ToInt32(object) but if you know off the top of your head then great - Which of the methods has the best performance in terms of speed, I would assume the (int)(Int16) method as we are explicitly telling it what to do, rather than just saying "here, figure out if this can be done". Thanks again.

Comment: @Rick - I've never tested, and would have to perform a test similar to the one you suggest. But I'd never do that test. I have a strong intuition that the effort to convert the result into an `int` is absolutely **swamped** by the amount of effort to query the database and (if not local) the network overheads. Don't try to optimize anything without first understanding where it's going to provide any benefit.

Comment: you're right!!! I keep saying to myself "stop trying to optimise code that doesn't need it!" but then I forget and get bogged down with it! Thanks again for your help :)