# C# using SqlDataReader I want to fetch the datetime value from a column

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm using :

```
string date1 = reader. GetDateTime(reader. GetOrdinal("firstMove"). ToString()
```

But it's throwing an exception especially if the value is null....

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Data Reader - handling Null column values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772025/sql-data-reader-handling-null-column-values)

Comment: You code won't _even_ compile. Can you please show short but complete program demonstrating? What exception you get exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
string date1=reader["coloumn name"].tostring();
```

Comment: Thanks. Now if I check is null or empty using an if statement and else if, how many times can I repeat the else if? Basically I need to check about 10 strings for null response

Answer (score 0):

The fact you're getting an exception would be easier to solve if you told us what kind of exception you get. Possible errors are:

1. Column is not `DateTime`, thus `GetDateTime` doesn't work at all
2. `firstMove` is not a valid column name at all, so you can not access that column

Assuming the column really exists and is of type `DateTime`
I tend to use the following:

```
DateTime? d = reader["firstMove"] as DateTime?;
```

This works pretty well. What you want would read

```
DateTime? d = reader["firstMove"] as DateTime?;
string dstring = d.HasValue ? d.Value.ToString() : "";
```

Or:

```
string date1 = !reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("firstMove")) ? reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("firstMove").ToString() : String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you, to use DateTime (or a nullable DateTime - DateTime?) instead of string, to handle dates.

If you want to follow this approach, you can use an Extension Method:

```
public static class IDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static DateTime GetDateTimeOrMinValue(this IDataReader dr, int position)
    {
        if (dr.IsDBNull(position))
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }

        return dr.GetDateTime(position);
    }

    public static DateTime? GetDateTimeOrNull(this IDataReader dr, int position)
    {
        if (dr.IsDBNull(position))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return dr.GetDateTime(position);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime dateA = reader.GetDateTimeOrMinValue(reader.GetOrdinal("firstMove"));

DateTime? dateB = reader.GetDateTimeOrNull(reader.GetOrdinal("firstMove"));
```

You can even improve the extension method, so it could receive the column name and find the ordinal position internally.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score -2):

Use as below, by using or function to check whether null or not null.

```
if(string1 || string2 ||string3)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. That is a) not an answer and b) not valid C# code.

Comment: This is not even valid syntax unless `string1`, `srting2` and `string3` are valid `bool` values. This "answer" is not helpful at all as it reads now. You could have invested the time it took to write your comment into improving your "answer" instead...