# How do I retrieve null values in my database to a view

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a simple Employee Database which allows me to add new a employee, with some of my textbox fields left empty (I'm using winform). It currently works ok in the database. It registers NULL values in place of the empty textboxes. My problem now is how to display all the employees from the database in a gridview:
When I run the program, it pops up a messagebox saying **"object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"**. Is it because 'age' and 'married' columns in my database contain some null values? Please help, I'm trying to understand how to use nullable types in c# with mssql database.

```
   public static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        List<Employee> empListToReturn = new List<Employee>();
        SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
        string queryStatment = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(queryStatment, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                emp.FirstName = reader["firstname"].ToString();
                emp.LastName = reader["lastname"].ToString();
                emp.Age = Convert.ToInt32(reader["age"]);
                emp.Married = (reader["married"]);

                empListToReturn.Add(emp);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return empListToReturn;

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772025/sql-data-reader-handling-null-column-values

Comment: @TimSchmelter I used emp.Age = reader[2] as int? ?? default(int); It is able to display age column but it displays 0 inplace of null in my gridview

Comment: you can do that but this one liner is almost code obfuscation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you can't convert `null` to other types.  Specifically in this case an `int`:

```
emp.Age = Convert.ToInt32(reader["age"]);
```

(Since value types can't be `null`.)

Simply check for `null` before converting:

```
if (reader["age"] == DBNull.Value)
    emp.Age = 0;
else
    emp.Age = Convert.ToInt32(reader["age"]);
```

---

**Edit:** As pointed out in a comment, there are multiple ways to do this.  Some may be more efficient than others.  For example:

```
if (reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("age")))
    emp.Age = 0;
else
    emp.Age = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("age")));
```

Unless the performance difference is significant, I'd probably prefer the former when using named columns instead of the ordinal, since this requires an extra method call to get the ordinal.  (Unless there's a string overload that I'm just not seeing on MSDN?)

---

Additionally, if you don't want `0` as an option, you might change the `.Age` property from `int` to `Nullable<int>` (or `int?` for short).  This would allow you to set a `null` value on that object:

```
if (reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("age")))
    emp.Age = null; // <-- here
else
    emp.Age = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("age")));
```

This is often very useful when there's a clear semantic difference between `0` (which is a valid value) and `null` (which is a lack of a value).

---

It's also worth noting that this code is bad practice:

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Not only is your `catch` block not actually handling the exception at all, it's actually *overwriting* the stack trace.  Which would make debugging more difficult.  Since the `catch` block isn't doing anything, just remove it entirely.  You don't need a `catch` in a `try/finally`.

Comment: Instead of comparing with `DBNull.Value` you can use `reader.IsDBNull` and instead of `Convert.ToInt32` you can use `reader.GetInt32`

Comment: I prefer the use of `int.TryParse()` myself.

Comment: I tried this: 
                    if (reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("age")))
                    {
                        emp.Age = null;    it retuns the list with empty data in place of null values
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        emp.Age = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("age"));
                    }

Comment: @FaithN: What do you mean by "empty data in place of null values"?  `null` values *are* empty data.  Is this working for you?

Comment: @David I mean the gridview is populated with firstname, lastname and age, but some of the cells for age is blank or empty in the gridview. These cells contain null values in the database. I want to show null on my gridview just as it is in the database

Comment: @FaithN: What exactly do you think `null` means?  If there is no value to show, then why do you expect it to show a value?  If you want to display some default in place of `null` then set that default on the object instead of setting it to `null`.

Comment: @David thanks, I appreciate.

Comment: @FaithN you can check for null and replace with `"[NULL]"` or something to indicate null as a string.