# Getting value from an int column causes "no implicit conversion between 'int' and null" error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

So I'm trying to retrieve a value from an `INT`, not an `INT NOT NULL`, column by means of

```
AnswerVal = !dataReader.IsDBNull(5) ? dataReader.GetInt32(5) : null
```

where `AnswerVal` is of type `int?` and I'm getting the compile-time error

> type of conditional expression cannot be determined because because
>   there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and null

Any idea what's  going wrong here?

And yes, I've looked at [SQL Data Reader - handling Null column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772025/sql-data-reader-handling-null-column-values), and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong because my inline if/else is equivalent to the answer there.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly cast expression to `int?`

Comment: Why are you even bothering checking for `null` when the column is `INT NOT NULL`.  Just make your model `int` and be done with it

Comment: int? AnswerVal = dataReader.IsDBNull(5) ? (int?)null : dataReader.GetInt32(5);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the value this way:

```
int? AnswerVal = !dataReader.IsDBNull(5) ? dataReader.GetInt32(5) : (int?)null;
```

There is no implicit conversion between `int` and `null`, but there is implicit conversion between `int` and `int?` and using `(int?)null` you are identifying the type of that null.

And of course when the column is defined as not null, you really don't need such check.

Comment: You dropped the `!` on the condition.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

> The condition must evaluate to true or false. If condition is true,
>   first_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. If condition is
>   false, second_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. Only one
>   of the two expressions is evaluated. *Either the type of
>   first_expression and second_expression must be the same*, or **an
>   implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.**

In your case the true statement and the false statement are of different types so you need to convert them. As [Reza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei) mentioned in the above answer. so the snippet will be :

```
AnswerVal = !dataReader.IsDBNull(5) ? dataReader.GetInt32(5) : (int?)null;
```