# Recovering double´s null

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, datareader

I have a table with a few fields, one of them is a Double type field which can contains null values...

Using ADO and SQLDATAReader I recover that field in a variable. I defined this variable as a: **Double, Double?, double, double?**... and I got the value (coming from de SQLDataReader) using **GetValue** (and doing a cast) or using a **GetDouble**... each one is crashing when the value is null.

The only this is working is defining this variable as a object, but I dont want it. Thinking in advance could be hard times handle this type in my project...

Quote: I have to differentiate the case when this value is 0 or null...

Any idea guys?

Edited:

```
Object.DoubleValue= (Double?)Datos.GetDouble(1);
Object.doubleValue= (double?)Datos.GetDouble(1);
```

Not working.

```
Object.ObjectValue= Datos.GetValue(1);
```

Working.

Comment: can you please share your code ?

Comment: Call `IsDbNull` *before* using `GetDouble` or use a micro-ORM like Dapper to abstract all this away. You should use `numeric` and `GetDecimal` instead of double too

Comment: what is your datatype in your database? sql server?

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772025/sql-data-reader-handling-null-column-values

Comment: @gsharp database is sql server.

Comment: @Frebin Francis code is so basic, but I posted.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I Tried and is working but I want to avoid it. My code will be more confused because I have so many classes and attributes...

Comment: I was more interested in the datatype defined on the column :) @EliasMP

Comment: @gsharp float... :P.

Comment: Try `GetFieldValue<double?>` method.

Comment: GetFieldValue doesn't work as well. @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: @gsharp - You're right: it cannot handle null. Well, then we can use the `GetSqlDouble` method.

Comment: Iv'e tried it. Then you have a type SqlDouble, if you try to access the variable.Value it raises an exception. you'll end again in if/else mode. @AlexanderPetrov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no out of the box method. But you could tweak it with an extension method like this:

(be aware its just a rough prototype that works in your case, but probably needs some checks and constraints etc)

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static T GetSmartValue<T>(this SqlDataReader r, int ordinal)
    {
        dynamic value = r.GetValue(ordinal);
        if (value == DBNull.Value)
        {
            value = null;
            return value;
        }

        return (T) value;
    }
}
```

then in your code

```
var x = yourReader.GetSmartValue<double?>(1);
```

Comment: Finally I desist... I will use your method gsharp. Quite elegant... Thanks Mate...

Comment: welcome. however i don't know what kind of application you are writing, but i use plain ado.net mostly only for quick n dirty stuff, for other i rely on dapper or EF. makes life easier :)

Comment: Hard to explain... but I need to use it... Thanks again gsharp... :)

Comment: yeah sometimes we can't pick our favorite tools .. been there too ;-) have a good weekend @EliasMP

Comment: You as well... Cheers @gsharp :)

Comment: What do you think about my first approach @gsharp? Defining a class with object attributes, and recovering the values from the DB as an object. I can paint them (in the view) directly without any cast...

Comment: @EliasMP well better to cast than having object in my opinion. however that always depends on what you want to do. as i don't have the full picture of your project it's difficult to say.

Comment: I haven´t all picture as well... LOL. Kind of using Devexpress, ADO, painting data, MVC, Entity,... Just asking, finally I used your method... Elegant... Cool!! Cheers mate...

Comment: nice solution, one optimization: return null in case of DBNull instead of return DBNull.Value

Comment: @gsharp, sry, yes... value=null;return value; ok, i got that... one line less: return null; :)

Comment: @swe return null doesn't work as well since it's not defined that T must be a class ;-) I'm assigning null to value because it's dynamic.