# How to pass the parameter to a postgre function and get data using ExecuteReader?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to retrieve all the columns from a table using ExecuteReader in C# application.Db is postgre.To test i created a console application following a tutorial which did showed how to query using a Function but not with passing parameters.The console application function for test

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Connect to a PostgreSQL database
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=postgres; " +
            "Password=pes;Database=pmc;");
        conn.Open();

        // Define a query
        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * from audit.exception_gl_accounts()", conn);

        // Execute the query and obtain a result set
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Output rows
        while (dr.Read())
            Console.Write("{0}\t{1} \n", dr[0], dr[1]);

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Here in NpgsqlCommand i sent the query without parameter to the function audit.exception_gl_accounts and it worked well.Now How do i pass a parameter to a function like this

> "SELECT * FROM sms.get_accounts_info(@AccountNumber);

I am trying to retrieve all 5 columns using this function and get those objects

```
    public static string GetAccountInfo(string accountNumber)
    {
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;User 
                            Id=postgres; " + "Password=pes;Database=pmc;");
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 
                           sms.get_accounts_info(@AccountNumber); ", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", accountNumber);
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
            Console.Write("{0}\t{1} \n", dr[0], dr[1]);
            return dr.ToString();
    }
```

Using the second sample code gives this error :

> {
>     "accountNumber": "Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader",
>     "balance": null,
>     "interestRate": 0,
>     "accountName": null,
>     "accountType": null
>   }

Any Help Appreciated.

**DETAILS UPDATED**

The Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("info")]
public IHttpActionResult GetAccountInfo([FromBody]AccountInfo 
accountinfo)
 {
accountinfo.accountNumber = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetAccountInfo
          (accountinfo.accountNumber);
            return Ok(accountinfo);
 }
```

Account Info Class

```
public class AccountInfo
    {
      public string accountNumber { get; set; }
      public string balance { get; set; }
      public int interestRate { get; set; }
      public string accountName { get; set; }
      public string accountType { get; set; }
    }
```

URI

> http://localhost:8080/v1/accounts/info

GetAccountsInfo

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sms.get_accounts_info(IN account_number_ character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(account_number character varying, account_name text, product character varying, interest_rate numeric, balance money) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY(
        SELECT a.account_number,
        c.customer_name,
            p.deposit_product_name, 
            a.interest_rate::numeric, deposit.get_balance(account_number_)
        FROM deposit.account_holders a 
        JOIN core.customers_view  c ON a.customer_id = c.customer_id
        JOIN core.deposit_products p ON a.deposit_product_id = p.deposit_product_id
        WHERE a.account_number = $1
    );
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION sms.get_accounts_info(character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: that does not look like an error. could this be the (valid) result of `dr.ToString()`? Is there any runtime error (exception)? is anything written to console? `Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader` would by the `dr` recordset type - not sure how that ends up as a value.

Comment: @dlatikay hello sir..there is nothing written to console..was looking  ways to get around and found that in a tutorial..this is a webapi project and passing accountNumber as parameter to the body.Help sir.i am loosing my hair because of this.How to pass parameter to a postgre function using npgsql command?thank you

Comment: I think you're doing it fine with the parameter already. To me it would look more like an issue with the presentation of the results. The output you included in your post, is that the string that `GetAccountInfo` returns, or something else?

Comment: @dlatikay i have updated the details sir.thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the plsql function GetAccountInfo returning? (please edit your post with the code). Are you sure it is returning two columns? Where is the "error" occurring? Try putting your code in a try/catch and display the error message. Note that you are looping through all results, but you return (=exit) at the 1st row. As @dlatikay writes, it looks a lot like dr.tostring

Comment: @JGH it is returning 5 columns sir..actually the code i put above for GetAccountInfo, i am testing looking through tutorials since hours to get execute.reader work..getting insane.I am not an expert.still learning.please pardon if too lame. i tried dr.ToString() because the message said CANNOT IMPLICITLY CONVERT TYPE NpgSql.NpgSqlDataReader to 'string' when i tried to return just return dr;

Comment: the reader is fine, forget about it (unless it throws an exception that you can catch in a [try..catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions) ). Your function returns 5 columns? Then you should read the 5 (dr[0] to dr[4]). Your function is returning 1 string, what should it be? (you may want to return nothing and just display the result for now). At last, make sure to read about handling [NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772025/sql-data-reader-handling-null-column-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without entity framework, you need to write the code that reads the values from the datareader into an instance of your `AccountInfo` class:

```
public static AccountInfo GetAccountInfo(string accountNumber)
{
    AccountInfo result = null;
    using(var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("..."))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using(var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sms.get_accounts_info(@AccountNumber); ", conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", accountNumber);
            using(var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if(dr.HasRows && dr.Read())
                {
                    result = new AccountInfo { 
                        accountNumber = dr["accountNumber"].ToString(),
                        balance = dr["balance"].ToString(),
                        interestRate = Convert.ToInt32(dr["interestRate"]),
                        accountName = dr["accountName"].ToString()
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that the return type of the function has been changed to `AccountInfo`, previously string. Also, it is limited to reading just one record, If one call to `sms.get_accounts_info` could return more than one record, it is a different story. I just assumed that `account_number` is a primary key in the `account_holders` table.

Some details need your attention, for example `balance` is money in database, but string in the class. Also I did not know if and how `product` (database) and `accountType` (class) would correspond, so I omitted it.

Database connections, commands, and datareaders are `IDisposable` and should be wrapped in `using` blocks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time sir...I know i lack understanding basic language constructs related to objects and populating objects and i am still learing.One last question perhaps- My controllers action  [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("info")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAccountInfo([FromBody]AccountInfo accountinfo)
        {
            accountinfo.AccountNumber = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetAccountInfo(accountinfo.AccountNumber);
            return Ok(accountinfo);
        }  it says cannot convert type AccountInfo to "string".

Comment: I think it should be `accountinfo = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetAccountInfo(....)` instead. So it will return the complete object with five fields, and not just the account number (which makes sense as input, but probably not as the only output).

Comment: Made it worked..had a small issue sir..you were godsend.Thanks a lot.:)

Comment: @dlatikay how do we map with EF?

Comment: this is a separate question, does not belong here IMO