# safe way to read from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

Is there a safer way to read from `SqlDataReader.GetFieldValue`, the value may be null at times.

**Error**

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException was thrown.

**Code**

```
var roles = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(reader.GetOrdinal("Roles"))
```

something like `TryGet` etc.

Comment: Have you tried tu put it in a try catch block to manage error?

Comment: for some reason I need to stay within the block and not jump out of it, I've to display null in the JSON output in such case, so that's why checking for null instead of catching and managing errors.

Comment: Check for null *before* trying to read

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772025/sql-data-reader-handling-null-column-values

Comment: var roles = (reader.GetOrdinal("Roles") == null) ? string.Empty : reader.GetFieldValue<string>(reader.GetOrdinal("Roles"))

Comment: @jdweng that's the answer. Thanls. On a side note is it fine If I use `reader.GetString` instead of `reader.GetFieldValue<string>`, the lateral seems verbose.