# Proble with input string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am programming in ASP.NET MVC using C# and I get this error:

> The input string is not formatted correctly

I have corroborated in the database and it is fine. So I would like to know if you can see the error. I want to clarify that both the dni and dnidos are `Float` in the database. But for some unknown reason it is not working in the code.

**Class:**

```
public double dniDos { get; set; }

public Solicitud(double dni, string codigo, decimal? monto, string soli,
            DateTime fechaSol, double? valnom, string desc,
            string apellido,
            string nombre,
            string domicilio, string numero,
            string piso, string dpto, string mono, string barrio,
            string zona, string localidad, string provincia,
            int? cp, string tipoDni, string fechaNac, string ocupacion,
            string tel, string cel,
            string email,
            string estadoCivil, string observaciones, 
            string nomdos, double dniDos, 
            string codagencia, string codCobrador, string cobdom,
            string ase, int cuo)
            {
            this.DniNumero = dni;
            this.Codigo = codigo;
            this.Monto = monto;
            this.Solicitudes = soli;
            this.fechaSol = fechaSol;
            this.ValNom = valnom;
            this.DescPlanActual = desc;
            this.Apellido = apellido;
            this.Nombre = nombre;
            this.Domicilio = domicilio;
            this.Numero = numero;
            this.Piso = piso;
            this.Dpto = dpto;
            this.Mono = mono;
            this.Barrio = barrio;
            this.acidzona = zona;
            this.Localidad = localidad;
            this.Provincia = provincia;
            this.CodigoPostal = cp;
            this.DniTipo = tipoDni;
            this.fechaNac=fechaNac;
            this.ocupacion = ocupacion;
            this.Telefono = tel;
            this.Celular = cel;
            this.email=email;
            this.estadoCivil=estadoCivil;
            this.observaciones = observaciones;
            this.nomDos = nomdos;
            this.dniDos = dniDos;
            this.agenciaCodigo = codagencia;
            this.codCobrador = codCobrador;
            this.cobDomicilio = cobdom;
            this.asesor = ase;
            this.cantCuo = cuo;
        }
```

SQL Connection:

```
public List<Solicitud> cargarDatosPDF(string sol)
        {
            List<Solicitud> salida = new List<Solicitud>();
            string con = "Data Source = dasdasd; Initial Catalog = ProvidusWeb; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = id; Password = pass";
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT DniNumero, codigo, monto, solicitud, " +
                    "FechaSolicitud, valnom, DescPlanActual, " +
                    "apellido, " +
                    "nombre, " +
                    "domicilio, numero," +
                    "piso, dpto, mono, barrio, " +
                    "acidzona, localidad, provincia, " +
                    "codigopostal, dnitipo, FechaNacimiento, ocupacion, " +
                    "telefono, celular, " + 
                    "mail, " +
                    "EstadoCivil, Observaciones, " +
                    "NomSegundoSus, DNIsegundoSus, " +
                    "AgenCob, CodCobrador, " +
                    "asesor, ancantcuoplan, " +
                    "CobradorDomicilio " +
                    " FROM V_SolicitudWeb " +
                    " WHERE solicitud = @sol ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sol", sol);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        double dni = Convert.ToDouble(dr["dninumero"]?.ToString());
                        string codigo = dr["codigo"]?.ToString();
                        decimal? monto = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["monto"]?.ToString());
                        string soli = dr["solicitud"]?.ToString();

                        DateTime fechaSolicitud = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["FechaSolicitud"]?.ToString());
                        double? valnom = Convert.ToDouble(dr["valnom"]?.ToString());
                        string desc = dr["descplanactual"]?.ToString();

                        string apellido = dr["apellido"]?.ToString();

                        string nombre = dr["nombre"]?.ToString();

                        string domicilio = dr["domicilio"]?.ToString();
                        string numero = dr["numero"]?.ToString();

                        string piso = dr["piso"]?.ToString();
                        string dpto = dr["dpto"]?.ToString();
                        string mono = dr["mono"]?.ToString();
                        string barrio = dr["barrio"]?.ToString();

                        string zona = dr["acidzona"]?.ToString();
                        string localidad = dr["localidad"]?.ToString();
                        string provincia = dr["provincia"]?.ToString();

                        int? cp = Convert.ToInt32(dr["codigopostal"]?.ToString());
                        string dnitipo = dr["dnitipo"]?.ToString();
                        string fechaNac = dr["FechaNacimiento"]?.ToString();
                        string ocupacion = dr["ocupacion"]?.ToString();

                        string tel = dr["telefono"]?.ToString();
                        string cel = dr["celular"]?.ToString();
                        
                        string email = dr["Mail"]?.ToString();

                        string estadoCivil = dr["EstadoCivil"]?.ToString();
                        if (estadoCivil == "C") 
                        {
                            estadoCivil = "Casado";
                        } else if (estadoCivil == "S")
                        {
                            estadoCivil = "Soltero";
                        }
                        else if (estadoCivil == "V")
                        {
                            estadoCivil = "Viudo";
                        }
                        else if (estadoCivil == "D")
                        {
                            estadoCivil = "Divorciado";
                        }

                        string observaciones = dr["Observaciones"]?.ToString();

                        string nomDos = dr["NomSegundoSus"]?.ToString();
                        double dniDos = Convert.ToDouble(dr["DNIsegundoSus"]?.ToString());

                        string codAgencia = dr["AgenCob"]?.ToString();
                        string codCobrador = dr["CodCobrador"]?.ToString();
                        string cobDom = dr["CobradorDomicilio"]?.ToString();

                        string ase = dr["asesor"]?.ToString();

                        int cantidadCuotas = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ancantcuoplan"]?.ToString());
                        
                        Solicitud p = new Solicitud(dni, codigo,monto, soli,
                            fechaSolicitud, valnom, desc, 
                            apellido,
                            nombre,
                            domicilio,numero,
                            piso, dpto,mono,barrio,
                            zona,localidad,provincia,
                            cp,dnitipo, fechaNac, ocupacion,
                            tel,cel,
                            email, 
                            estadoCivil, observaciones, 
                            nomDos, dniDos, 
                            codAgencia, codCobrador, codCobrador, 
                            ase, cantidadCuotas);
                        salida.Add(p);
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
                conexion.Close();
                return salida;
            }
        }
```

The error happens on this line of code:

```
double dniDos = Convert.ToDouble(dr["DNIsegundoSus"]?.ToString());
```

[image]

Comment: What is actual string value?

Comment: Null @GuruStron

Comment: You cannot convert null to int like that.

Comment: May be the solution can be modify the query to something like that: `ISNULL(DNIsegundoSus, 0)'DNIDOS'`, right? @SudipShrestha

Comment: @FrancoJoelBalsamo you can also do it client side.

Comment: There are many ways you can do it on C# side. You can try Double.TryParse or dr.IsDBNull("DNIsegundoSus"). I recommend doing it on C# side instead of IsNull(field, 0) on SP.

Comment: @FrancoJoelBalsamo please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1772037/2501279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trying to convert something that throws a FormatException.  If you are able to do so then do something like this

```
ISNULL(dr[DNIsegundoSus], 0) as 'DNIsegundoSus'
```

in your SELECT.  If you are unable to do so and need to show a null you might want to return it as a string and let the controller determine to pass 'NULL, blank, '', etc to the view.